# Can I format the decimal value in a masked column in the table itself?

Tags: mysql, mask

I have a column with values like **${0}/month** where I put decimal value in the placeholder with stuff function. Is there any way to format {0} value to 2 decimal places based on another column having not null value?

I mean, can I do something in the table creation code to show 2 decimal places rather than doing it in the SQL query?

Comment: You could do it using a generated column.

Comment: Why do you put formatting in a table column, instead of doing it in the reporting code?